# MYSQL Realtime Display

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wanna that my website shows up the coins from every user and when I add some coins to a user I wanna that he don't need to reload the page to get the correct amount.

So short i just wanna show the mysql value in realtime.

My Code

```html
                <?php
                if($admin == 1)
    {
    echo'
    <li class="text-muted menu-title">Admin Panel</li>
    <li class="has_sub admin-content">
                <a href="#" class="waves-effect '; if($page=="ad"){echo'subdrop';} echo'"><i class="ti-user"></i><span>Admin</span> </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled '; if($page=="ad"){echo'"style="display: block;"';} echo'" style="">
    <li><a href="apu.php">Premium users</a></li>
    <li><a href="abu.php">Banned users</a></li>
    <li><a href="au.php">Users</a></li>
                </ul>
    </li>
    ';
                         
    }
 if(isset($_GET["action"]))
{
 if($_GET["action"] == "view")
 {
  $sid = $_GET["id"];
 }
 if($_GET["action"] != "view")
 {
  echo '<script>location.href="index.php" </script>';
 }

}
if(!isset($_GET["action"]))
{
 if(isset($_SESSION["steamid"]))
 {
  $sid= $_SESSION['steamid'];
 }
 else
 {
  echo '<script>location.href="index.php" </script>';
 }
}

$sid=mysql_real_escape_string($sid);

$exists=fetchinfo("steamid","users","steamid",$sid);

if(!$exists)
{
 echo '<script>location.href="index.php" </script>';
}

 $crdts=fetchinfo("credits","users","steamid",$sid); 

 
 if($reg)
 {
  $reg2date=date('Y-m-d', $reg);
 }
 else
 {
  $reg2date='Unknown';
 }
 if($gp==0  || $gw==0)
 {
  $wr=0;
 }
 else
 {
  $wr=($gw/$gp)*100;
 }
 
 if($premium==1)
 {
 $id=$_SESSION['steamid'];
 $time=time();
 $puntil = fetchinfo("puntil","users","steamid","$id");
 if($puntil<=$time)
 {
  
  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `premium`='0' WHERE `steamid`='$id'");
  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `profile`='1' WHERE `steamid`='$id'");
  
 }
}

?>
  
  
             <div class="credits1">
                                        <li class="text-muted menu-title">Credits</li>
                                        <br>
          </div>
          <div id="credits"><?php echo $crdts; ?></div>
```

Thanks for your attention and i hope you can help me.

Comment: TO change things without reloading you need to use ajax.
have a look at this
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp

Comment: you should also look at web sockets. this will ensure you only retrieve new data from your database when needed. I think for php http://socketo.me/

Comment: This involves quite a lot more than the question alludes to. In order for real time updates to occur, you need to have a mechanism to send requests to the server, query the appropriate tables and manipulate the DOM after the response has been received. Ajax and websockets are two common mechanisms to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax request to get asynchronous data from the source. Most common way is javascript ajax request, but i assume you already know jquery, if not you can get it quickly, see: http://jquery.com

First you need to set a php file that return data from database you need

assume ajax.php

```
// make db connection
// get related data from db
// return the data (coins)

// set result array
$result = [
   'coins' => $dbResult['coins']
];

// you can use json, so that you can easily manipulate it
// encode to json the array
$json = json_encode($result);

echo $json;

// or you could jus echo the coins as well, like:
echo $dbResult['coins'];
```

ajax.js

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/getWeather",
      dataType: json, // if you get a json, using this better than parsing result to json
      success: function( result ) {
       // updating coins in the DOM for json return
       $( "selector to show coins" ).text(result.coins);

       // or updating coins for plain text return
       $( "selector to show coins" ).text(result);
      }
    });
});
```

You can update or add new features to your code as well.